# Woocommerce pay with credit card with Bank of Cyprus

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, transactions, bank

I am creating a website with WordPress, Woocommerce and Wcmp so people can create account upload their music and sell it.

Our company has open in Bank of Cyprus so we need to create a connection with the bank.

How can we create a credit card payment(visa, mastercard...) on this website so the money go to that bank? I haven't done this before. (I managed to do the PayPal transaction though.)

Thank you.